# Read Applanix.00n data

Tags: gps, binary

I have some GNSS/INS data coming from an Applanix POS AV 510 system. They are a series of binary files named "applanix.000", "applanix.001" and so forth.

Is there any way to read them with an open source/freeware code or software?

The file provider didn't provide any software and the only thing I could find online ([pktrigg/posmv](https://github.com/pktrigg/posmv)) doesn't seem to work on these kind of files.

Comment: applanix is a proprietary format (trimble) https://geospatial.trimble.com/products-and-solutions/applanix-pospac-mms you will need to purchase it to use it.